# SQL Oracle - Compare two table schemas(column Data Types and size, not the values) between DEV and TEST

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to compare two tables DEV-TABLEA and QA-TABLEA in order to determine if there is any difference in datatypes, column lengths, or additional columns, here I am not concerned with the actual data; I would appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: just query `user_tab_cols` dictionary view for both.

Comment: If querying as per Barbaros's comment  is not an option, you may try features like "Database Diff" in Oracle SQL Developer or "Compare Databases" in PLSQL Developer

Comment: I used SQL Developer Database Diff, but it did not give me an exact difference between two table columns

Comment: @krishna Please provide an example of what SQL Developer gives vs the exact difference.

Answer (score 0):

As you do use SQL Developer (but reported that it didn't do what you wanted), then: are you using the latest version? Maybe yours doesn't do that correctly/completely. Because, on my 21.4.2, it works just fine.

For testing purposes, I created a `test` table in `scott` schemas in two different databases:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@db1
Connected.

SQL> create table test(id number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> connect scott/tiger@db2
Connected.

SQL> create table test(id number, name varchar2(20), address varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

As you can see, table in `db2` has modified `name` column length and additional (`address`) column.

Running **Database Diff** produces the following result (exclamation mark icons warn you that there are some issues there; I chose the `test` table):

[image]

Both `name`  and `address` have been marked, so ... it *works* OK (at least, I think so).